# How to get an updated value of repository variable in the same workflow?

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a workflow with a job consisting of two steps. The first one is updating the repo level variable ([GitHub documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.8/rest/actions/variables#update-a-repository-variable)). The second outputs this value using the **vars.** context.

```
    - name: Set new value
      run: |
        gh api \
          --method PATCH \
          -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
          -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
          /repos/ORG/REPO/actions/variables/MY_VAR \
          -f name='MY_VAR' \
          -f value="1.2.3"
    - name: Echo new value
      run: |
        echo ${{ vars.MY_VAR}}
```

But I'm still getting the old value in the second step although the value was definitely updated (I can check this using both the UI and API call).

It looks like the **vars.** are initialized only at the beginning of the execution. Is there any way to 'reload' them during the execution? I definitely can get the updated value using the API, but it looks like an overhead.

Answer (score 0):

I think usage of environment variables is to be more of a static solution to store different environment specific declarations, anyway - if you need a variable value during runtime, try using unix export sub-command, like

```
export MY_VAR = '123'
```

And after your runtime is finished - put an updated value back using github cli or rest api or whatever you like

Answer (score 0):

I had similar workflow, I was updating my variable on different jobs steps, only one got updated, it seems the value is cached at execution time, I had to pull the current value using `gh` REST API, and updated it with `gh` CLI (I prefer the CLI, but listing variables truncates the value) for each of the steps.

If you want to set, and get the updated value, you could achieve that with the combination of `gh` CLI (for brevity) and `gh` REST API:

```yaml
- name: Set new value
  run: |
    gh variable set MY_VAR --body "1.2.3"

- name: Get new value, pipe it with jq to print just the value to STDOUT
  run: |
    gh api \
      --method GET \
      -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
      -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
      /repos/ORG/REPO/actions/variables/MY_VAR | jq -r '.value'
```